# Angular 6 Injects ParentService instead of ChildService

Tags: angular

`AppComponent` receives `ParentService` instance instead of `ChildService` when using the following code:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class ParentService {
  name = 'parent';  
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class ChildService extends ParentService {
  name = 'child';  
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  logs = [];

  constructor(childService: ChildService) {
    this.logs.push('childService instanceof ChildService: ' + (childService instanceof ChildService));
    this.logs.push('childService instanceof ParentService: ' + (childService instanceof ParentService));
    this.logs.push('childService name: ' + childService.name);
  }
}
```

How to get `ChildService` Instance? Thanks.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypq7ag

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. You should report it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your fast response :)

Comment: Strangely it works fine, If `ParentService` is not provide at the `root`. i.e commenting out `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263722/angular-6-services-and-class-inheritance Here's your solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcbm2o?file=src/app/app.component.ts